# Replace dot . in make file recipe

Tags: shell, makefile

In a make rule like below. I want to replace to the dot "." character

```
APPS := example.helloworld example.sample

$(APPS):
    @appdir=`echo $@|sed -e s/\./\//`
    # do something...
```

It doesn't work as make does not escape the "\." and "/" characters. Is there an alternative to this?

Note: I can't change app names and I can't use gnu make.

Comment: use `sed -e 's/\.//g'`

Comment: 'g' isn't required as there is only one ".". The issue here is that make does not escape the "." properly.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround using shell variables. It works like this:

```
APPS := example.helloworld example.sample

$(APPS):
    @dot="\."; \
    @slash="\/"; \
    appdir=`echo $@|sed -e s/$$dot/$$slash/`
    # do something...
```